# Algorithm to check if a matrix is elementary

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science

I'm currently writing a homework problem for a linear algebra course and I'm trying to come up with an algorithm to check if a matrix is elementary. That is, to check if it is one of the three forms as given on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix). I currently have the code below to check if it is the first type. Is there a way to improve this or modify it to check the other two cases? Or is there an entirely better way? I feel like I'm close, but for some reason I'm struggling. Thanks in advance!

```
  my @d = $A->dimensions;
      # type1 - row swap, type2 - mult row by const, type3 - add mult of row to another
      my $type1 = 1; my $type2 = 1; my $type3 = 1; 
  for (my $j = 0; $j < $d[0]; $j++) {
    $hasones[$j] = 0;  # count the number of ones in each column
  }
  for (my $i = 1; $i <= $d[0]; $i++) {
    my $nonzerocount = 0; # number of nonzeros in each row
        my $onecount = 0; # number of ones in each row
    for (my $j = 1; $j <= $d[0]; $j++) {
      if ($A->element($i,$j) != 0) {
            $nonzerocount++;
            if ($A->element($i,$j) == 1) {
              $onecount++;
              $hasones[$j-1]++;
            }
          }
        }
        if ($nonzerocount != 1 || $onecount != 1) { # only one nonzero allowed and it has to be one for type1
          $type1 = 0;
        }
      }
      $numonesokay = 1;
  for ($j = 0; $j < $d[0]; $j ++) {
    if ($hasones[$j] != 1) {
      $numonesokay = 0;  # can't have more than one one in each column
        }
      }
      if ($type1 == 1 && $A->det != 1 && $numonesokay == 1) {
    return 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a different trick.
Look at the properties for elementary matrices on the wikipedia page.

If $A$ is of the first type, you have that the inverse of this matrix is itself: $A^{−1}=A$ or $A^2=Id$.
Therefore, to check if it is of the first type, you can multiply it with itself and see if the resulting matrix is the identity matrix.

Can you do something similar in the other cases?

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but any symmetric orthogonal matrix also has this property and so it may not necessarily be elementary?

Comment: Okay... I think you can do like this. First of all check if all the columns have norm 1. If this is not true, it cannot be type 1. Now take $A-Id$ then on the diagonal you can only have $0$ and $-1$, if it is not true, it cannot be type 1. Let $i$ and $j$ be the column indices such that the elements on the diagonal are $-1$. Now you only have to check that if the $i$-th element of the $j$-th column is $1$ and the $j$-th elemnt of the $i$-th column  is $1$. I think it should work.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with this. I actually just did something similar by counting the number of 1's on the diagonal and nonzero elements off the diagonal. The three cases are:
(i) all ones on diagonal, and one off diagonal
(ii) all ones except one nonzero not equal to one, and no off diagonal entries
(iii) all ones except for two zero entries on diagonal, and the two nonzeros off diagonal must be one and symmetric, i.e., A(i,j) = A(j,i)